# Updating a Mysql Table through Email

Tags: php, mysql

I am using php.
I just want to add a row to my mysql table through e-mail
A email from  secret email address (just like they do for uploading content in facebook and youtube) will be added to the table.

Comment: Who "they" do that and who are you referencing to in your question?

Comment: @zerkms — users of the specified services

Comment: @David Dorward: haven't seen that in facebook. Could you point me?

Comment: http://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=facebook+upload+by+email

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Get the email into your script

   - use something like procmail to push it there when it arrives or
   - run the script from a schedular (like cron) and poll your POP or IMAP server for new mail.
2. Parse the email
3. Use the data as you would from any other source

Comment: +1 @meadhikari: If using Postfix, also check out: http://jeroensmeets.net/setup-postfix-to-forward-incoming-email-to-php/

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a **service or a standalone software application** that continuously checks for new emails for a particular email account. Whenever a new email is received you can verify its authentication and perform the required operation on the database.

For this you will need this software constantly checking for emails like an outlook or anyother email agents.

*Apart from this i am not sure whether you can achieve this through any other aproach...*