# Remotely update website via ?email

Tags: php, mysql, html, email

I have a php page with a MySQL db behind it which my clients use.

At times I have to add a 'System Message' to the top of the page to tell them about planned maintenance or upcoming changes or whatever.

At the moment I do this by opening up the PHP page by FTP and adding a bit of HTML text.

My question is, can you think of a way where I could, for instance, email an address which would take the content of the email and post the text on the Php page as my 'System Message'?

Or it wouldnt have to be an email, but some hands off way I could add text without opening the FTP or mySQL db - ideally that I could just send from my phone via 3g..

Look forward to your ideas...

Comment: I'm just spitballing here, as I've never done anything like this. I would imaging you would have to set up some kind of listener to a specific mailbox on your server that would essentially echo the commands from the email to the CLI which would execute your PHP script.

Comment: @Matt I thought it was important enough to be pointed out, I'm glad someone told me so when I first used SO. I just searched in meta and noticed that you are right, it is not considered appropriate. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Thanks all.  Apologies, did not know I had to accept.  Have now done this.  DaveRandom - Take your point re email.  The HTML form idea is interesting.  I could mobile-optimise it and access from my phone

Comment: @Matt thanks for your thoughts.  What you describe sounds beyond my knowledge, so I might try the HTML form idea...

Comment: @highfidelity it's beyond mine, too haha. I was just throwing it out there. To reiterate, it's not a secure method, nor is it the easiest. The answers below are much better suggestions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Updating a Mysql Table through Email](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468358/updating-a-mysql-table-through-email)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't suggest you to use an email, but rather have an admin interface with a `<textarea>` or a [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) or [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/) where you can change the text, click save, and it'd change an external HTML page (`custom_content.html`) to whatever content you input using post and `file_put_contents("custom_content.html", $_POST["text"])`. You'd have to change your main site to `require_once` or `include_once` this html page though.

**If you decide to use the admin system method, either make sure your URL has some sort of uniqueness (random characters) or make a login that you have to fill out before using it first, as both of these methods, if exposed, could be used to XSS attack your site**.

That said, if you want the email system (again, I'm not recommending you to), you could have a cron job that connects to your email server with IMAP or POP (using existing libraries) and check for new messages, and if those messages are from a certain email and include a certain subject, and then do the same thing back-end as in the admin system (replacing the HTML files content, and including it on the main page).

Comment: Thanks h2ooooo. Your admin interface idea is interesting.  As I said in the post, I would ideally like something which I could send from my phone - maybe there are editors like CKEditor & TinyMCE (which I had not seen before - thanks) that are available in a mobile form.. I will have to look.  Youve given me some ideas though

Comment: @highfidelity You're welcome. Don't forget to accept the answer you found most helpful. Also, if it's just text (and not HTML) you don't need CKEditor or TinyMCE, but rather just a `textarea`.

Answer (score 0):

If it is running PHP already why not create some kind of back-end where you (and/or other people) can login and add messages. That shouldn't be too hard.

I wouldn't go for e-mail. This would be very hard to stay secure. If your address leaks, people can put anything on it. Of course you could find something for it, but it just isn't the right way of doing this.

Depending on what your future needs could be create a simple back-end and extend it (or keep in mind) as too what your future plans maybe. Think in the lines of user- and rights management, message categories, etc.

Comment: Thanks Gerald.  I guess I was looking for something as simple as sending an email or text - but with that simplicity would come security issues, as you point out. Future plans do include user rights management so your thoughts are spot on

Comment: Well as far as a text or mobile issues are concerned, you could, as a follow-up create a mobile interface for the same back-end so you can also post a message through your cell nice and easy.

Answer (score 0):

This might help: [Update website via email](https://www.sitemailcms.com)

Using our service, you can send emails to quickly and easily update your website instantly. Whatever you put in your emails will appear on your website exactly the way you type it, including special formatting, pictures and other attachments.